# Wrong patch for nvidia-331?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, dkms

I tried to install the most recent `nvidia-331` driver (ubuntu-x-swat repository).

However, it seems like the installer tries to apply a wrong patch (3.10 patch, but I have a 3.11 kernel) -> the installation fails.

```
me@pc ~ $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
[...]
Loading new nvidia-331-331.62 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.11.0-12-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.11.0-12-generic
Error! Application of patch buildfix_kernel_3.10.patch failed.
Check /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331/331.62/build/ for more information.
```

How can I force `dkms` to apply the correct patch?

Comment: Found a solution for my situation (while this is *not* a solution for the problem itself): Installed a newer kernel, namely 3.13. Afterwards, the friver compiled fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you solved your problem by upgrading, but here's how I did it:

According to dkms.conf, the 3.10 patch should be applied for both 3.10 and 3.11 kernels, but I guess somewhere along the way the patch became unnecessary.

The solution is to edit `/usr/src/nvidia-331-xxx.yy/dkms.conf`.  Change the line saying

```
PATCH_MATCH[0]="^3.1[01]"
```

to

```
PATCH_MATCH[0]="^3.10"
```

and then reconfigure the package:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-331
```